# How to evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{100}e^{x-[x]}$

Tags: integration

What precisely is $[x]$ and how to evaluate such an integral?

Comment: I think $[x]$ is floor function. This integral is same for $\sum_{n=0}^{99} \int_n^{n+1} e^{x-n} dx$.

Comment: Ok but how to evaluate such an integral? @tetori

Comment: Probably $[x]$ is an alternative notation for $\lfloor x \rfloor$, the greatest integer (a.k.a. floor) function.

Comment: @user2493976 : Just evaluate it as $$e^{-n}\int_n^{n+1}e^xdx = e^{-n}(e^{n+1}-e^n) = e-1$$ Now add them all up.

Comment: Yup got it thanks

Comment: @tetori The answer should give 100( $e - 1$) from that

Answer (score 2):

[x] is the greatest integer function.

[5.6]=5,[-5.6]=-6

Any real number,x can be written in the form of $$x=[x]+\{x\}$$
where {x} is the fractional part of x and always lies between 0 and 1.

Hence x-[x]={x}.

Hence we get
$$\int_{0}^{100}e^{x-[x]}dx=\int_{0}^{100}e^{\{x\}}dx$$
The function is now periodic and can be rewritten as
$$\int_{0}^{100}e^{\{x\}}dx=100\int_{0}^{1}e^xdx$$
As {x}=x when x$\in$[0,1]

Comment: This is quite informative but  Prahlad Vaidyanathan and teori's comments also solve it in a simpler manner

Answer (score 0):

$[x]$ would denote the floor function.  Compare $x-[x]$ on the intervals [0,1] and [1,2], and you should see what the general pattern is.  Tetori's comment is essentially the same thing, though if you think of it more you can simplify one little step further.  Worst case scenario, you evaluate each of the integrals in his comment through subsitution rule.